# Google Tag Manager with disabled Javascript doesn't fire

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I try to implement a GTM call that executes Analytics tracking.
When I use the normal JS interface with

```
{"event": "fire"}
```

It fires well, when I try to use the no javasript approach:

http://www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?GTM-XXXXX&event=fire

it doesn't seem to do anything to the analytics counts.

Have you encountered such a thing?

Comment: Sgoldy, are you using Data Layer?

Comment: I use dataLayer where JS is available, but when I need to execute something on non-JS device I concatenate the data to the url query string. GTM doesn't seem to fire the JS related pixels. Any workaround?